# Move directory from queue directory Bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to implement directory Queue.

I have the following directories:

```
Q_Dir
     folder1
        subfolder1
           ...
              subfolderN
                 files1....filesN+X

     ....

Target_Dir
     folder1
         subfolder1
            ....
            subfolderN
                files1...filesN

     ....
```

I want to move maximum X files from `Q_Dir` to `Target_Dir`.

Pseudo code:

```
While True:
    totalFiles = Count of total files in Target_Dir
    If totalFiles < X then:
       Move X-totalFiles files From Q_Dir to Target_Dir
    Else
        Sleep 5 seconds
```

I looking for the best solution in Linux bash script to do it

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've never heard of a *"directory queue"*. What's the point of this please?

Comment: @ArmoArmo : Why not storing the pathes of all directories below Q_Dir in an array, count the number of directories below Target_Dir (say this number is `Y`), and then move the first X-Y entries of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following implementation of the pseudo-code. It is a one-to-one implementation. Possible to improve, if more details will be available.

```
S=Q_Dir
T=Target_Dir
X=6
mkdir -p $T
while true ; do
   t_count=$(find $T -type f | wc -l)
   if [[ "$t_count" -lt "$X" ]] ; then
       readarray -t -n "$((X-t_count))" files <<< "$(cd $S && find . -type f)"
       echo "F=${#files[@]}"
       for f in "${files[@]}" ; do
           d=${f%/*}
           mkdir -p $T/$d
           mv $S/$f $T/$d/
       done
       sleep 3
   else
       sleep 5
   fi
done
```

Note that the code does not provide atomic update - if multiple instances of the script will be executing against the same source or target folder.

Comment: Is it possible to replace "$(cd $S && find . -type f)" with another command? In case I have a lot of files find command take a lot of time to finish

Comment: @ArmoArmo You can modify the script as needed. You can add filters to the find command, or use any other command that will return list of files (relative to to the Q_Dir).

Comment: I don't have more filters, all the files are .json, Which other command can I use? Thanks!

Comment: You can add -name ‘*.json’ to the find commands, it will restrict the find to pick only those files.